# Multi Variable Calculus Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image][image]

Please help me with this multi-variable calculus question given a Taylor Polynomial of degree 1.

Comment: Yes my work is attached. Not sure if I solved it correctly. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: You should retag it though. This is about multivariable calculus, not calculus of variations.

Comment: thank you for the help guys. I'm not sure why I didn't see a tag for multivariable calc. I will look for it on my next question.

Comment: Amzoti, Thank you. Your right, I missed the negative. Therefore, the shortest distance will be sqrt(2).

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Yes, can you show me? Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything looks extremely clear. I finished up the question and got sqrt(2) as my final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sign issue.

The function is:

$$f(x,y) = \ln(1 + x^2 - y)$$

The first-degree Taylor Polynomial is given by:

$$f(x, y) \approx L(x, y) = f(a, b) + f_x(a, b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)~~\mbox{for}~~ (x, y) ~~\mbox{near}~~ (a,b) = (0,0)$$

So we have:

- $f(0, 0) = 0$
- $f_x(x, y) = \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2 - y} \rightarrow f_x(0,0) = 0$
- $f_y(x, y) = -\dfrac{1}{1+x^2 - y} \rightarrow f_y(0,0) = -1$

Thus:

$$L(x,y) = f(0,0) + f_x(0,0)(x-0) + f_y(0,0)(y-0) = 0 + 0(x-0) -1(y-0) = -y$$

Now you should finish it off.